# Reuse firefox icons using SDK addon in panel html view

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to make my first addon in firefox, so i'm using jpm as recommended :

```
var panel = panels.Panel({
  contentURL: './view/downloads.html',
  contentScriptFile: [
    './../lib/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
    './contentScript.js'
  ]
});
```

As i understand there was before xul (xml + moz DTD stuff) that allowed to make "mozilla native" interfaces.

But how do i for example use some icons (for instance the download icon, or the host native generic icon for image, file etc) in my html?
What are the possibilities to make my html panel look more native (even there are already some styles applied like gray background etc) ?

I could not find some more complete info on making interfaces on the mdn .

Comment: We still do it the same way, we do xhtml files, thats just html with the xul for localzation (fro mthe dtd stuff): https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/xhtml-xul here is a simple example of an html5 app that is loczalized, so its made with xhtml, https://github.com/Noitidart/ZooniverseXpert the large file is the angular library file so dont be intimidated.

Comment: Thanks i'll look forward through your links :P

Comment: Also i just found what i was looking for : resource:///chrome/browser/skin/classic/browser/ these are icons used in firefox so i can reuse some in my addon

Comment: Also for anyone reading i just understood that moz-icon:///home/kwaadpepper/wprojects/firetest/zepto.min.js?size=32&state=normal gives you the file icon, you can examine things using using debugger CTRL+MAJ+C on a about:downloads opened tab.